# Change the value of ENUM in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to change the value of an ENUM in a mySQL database that will help identify when a user is logged on or logged off on a website to be displayed to all users of the site. I set an ENUM column with possible values of 0 and 1. 0 being logged off, and 1 being logged on. But it doesnt seem to be changing anything. Here is my code:

```
    //LOGIN
session_start();

$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($query) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $userid = $row[0];
    $dbusername = $row[1];
    $dbpassword = $row[2];
    $email = $row[4];
    $status = $row[7];
    $permit = $row[6];
    $active = $row[5];
    $fname = $row[8];
    $lname = $row[9];
    $dob = $row[10];
    $signupdate = $row[3];
    $ipadd = $row[11];
    $loggedin = $row[12];
}

if ($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $userid;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['status'] = $status;
    $_SESSION['permit'] = $permit;
    $_SESSION['email_activation'] = $active;
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $fname;
    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $lname;
    $_SESSION['dob'] = $dob;
    $_SESSION['sign_up_date'] = $signupdate;
    $_SESSION['ipv4'] = $ipadd;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $loggedin;

    $sql = "UPDATE username SET loggedin = '1'";
    header("Location: ../main.php");
```

Comment: First: You forget the where clause. Second: Be careful when storing numbers in a ENUM type field, as they can be treated as index instead values. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html for more info.

Comment: it looks as if my primary key is id. so i tried this:
$sql = "UPDATE username SET loggedin = '1' WHERE id = $userid";
but it still didnt work. :-(

Comment: Not username use table name which is users.See below answer .

Comment: Just a suggestion. If you want to store a "boolean" values, which seems to be your case, tinyint(1) is usually used for this, where 0 means false and non-zero value means true.

Comment: thanks. that seems the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your update query with this one

```
"UPDATE users SET loggedin = '1' where `id` = $userid ";
```

Comment: it looks as if my primary key is id. so i tried this:
$sql = "UPDATE username SET loggedin = '1' WHERE id = $userid";
but it still didnt work. :-(

Comment: Not username use table name which is users

Comment: Updated my answer with your primary key.Now just paste this query .

Comment: its still not working. perhaps i placed the code in a bad spot? should i put it on the page the user is redirected to upon logging in?

Answer (score 0):

```
   //LOGIN
session_start();

$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($query) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $userid = $row[0];
    $dbusername = $row[1];
    $dbpassword = $row[2];
    $email = $row[4];
    $status = $row[7];
    $permit = $row[6];
    $active = $row[5];
    $fname = $row[8];
    $lname = $row[9];
    $dob = $row[10];
    $signupdate = $row[3];
    $ipadd = $row[11];
    $loggedin = $row[12];
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET loggedin = '1' where id = '$userid'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

}

if ($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $userid;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['status'] = $status;
    $_SESSION['permit'] = $permit;
    $_SESSION['email_activation'] = $active;
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $fname;
    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $lname;
    $_SESSION['dob'] = $dob;
    $_SESSION['sign_up_date'] = $signupdate;
    $_SESSION['ipv4'] = $ipadd;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $loggedin;

    header("Location: ../main.php");
```

Comment: mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 $sql = "UPDATE users SET loggedin = '1' WHERE id = $userid"; 
 header("Location: ../main.php");

still not working..

Comment: Now check it please.

Comment: @BuddyRoach, actually just now i have checked, table name was incorrect, instead of users, it was username. Corrected it and now check please.

Comment: yeah table name is users. i fixed it. but its still not dynamically changing the value. im testing this on WAMP

Comment: Dear @BuddyRoach, can you please send me files that you are using?